# Use of rhino mocks to return specific results based on a provided Expression

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I use a generic repository to access data in C#, the method signature of which is this:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = "")
```

this is then used in an MVC controller (for example) in the following ways

```
var users = UnitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(
    u => u.Id == userId, null, "CreatedEmployer,CreatedEmployer.CreatedByUser");

var checkUser = UnitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(u => u.UserName == email)
                                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to be able to mock these calls using RhinoMocks and receive specific results based on the expression that was called. The pseudo code below demonstrates what I want to achieve e.g.

```
UnitOfWork.UserRepository.Expect(
    u => u.Get(Arg<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>.Matches(u.UserName == "jim")))
                         .Return(new List<User>() { userJim });

UnitOfWork.UserRepository.Expect(
    u => u.Get(Arg<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>.Matches(u.UserName == "jo left ages ago")))
                         .Return(new List<User>() );
```

I have tried using .WhenCalled but it does not seem to have the behaviour I want which is when matching a provided an exact provided expression, return some specific data:

```
.WhenCalled(invocation => {
    var predicate = invocation.Arguments.First() as Expression<Func<User, bool>>;
    ... Do something here
})
```

I've been trawling the internet for a while on this but have not managed to dig up a decent solution, most of the solutions consist of ignoring the arguments which works so long as you only call the repo once in a method e.g.

```
UserRepository.Expect(u => u.Get()).IgnoreArguments()
              .Return(new List<User> { CurrentUser });
```

This has now proved inadequate and I need something a bit more robust and specific. I am only really interested in the first argument. I need a solution to the above but if a solution does not exist for RhinoMocks then I'd be interested in any mocking framework where testing expressions was easier to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of the solution proposed by Sunny. Thanks for his advice and the steer to the solution for RhinoMocks.

For all tests you have an object called which is all the data that might ever be returned from any of your calls to the repository. In my case this is the users data set:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
```

Then at each arrange you add new users

```
users.Add(new User() { username="jim" });
users.Add(new User() { username="jo left ages ago" });
```

Then you call once to Expect. This sets up any call to the repo to query the data you have provided. For some reason this does not work with two calls to expect. To Rhino Mocks it only appears as if one call has been made:

```
baseController.UnitOfWork.UserRepository.Expect(u => u.Get(Arg<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>.Is.Anything, Arg<Func<IQueryable<User>, IOrderedQueryable<User>>>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
    .WhenCalled(invocation =>
        {
        var predicate = invocation.Arguments.First() as Expression<Func<User, bool>>;
        var query = predicate.Compile();
        invocation.ReturnValue = users.Where(query);
        });
```

As an aside, it still doesn't fit nicely with the way calls to SpecFlow's Given statements setup the expectations. What natural statement do you associate with setting up the Expect? But it does answer my original question.

Comment: I like better AAA syntax where you will have the right resultsyou use `Stub()` instead of `Expect()`. I haven't used rhino for a long time, but as far as I remember, `Expect()` is meant to be used when you want to verify the call. With AAA, you don't have to verify, as you test the behavior - if the stub provides the right data, the method under test will produce the right result. Otherwise it will not.

Answer (score 0):

I have [answered similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17579575/8220) using Moq. You can use the same approach with Rhino.

The key is to use a real (or mocked) data set, and run the expressions against it.

Comment: ok, it works for the first time it is called. What if you call it multiple times? I think this is back to the same problem. Because you have set up expectations around the Get method and ignored the arguments it will use the data supplied for the first expectation that you set up which in my case won't satisfy the condition. The alternative would be to set up all data needed by ALL calls to the user repo in one hit. This may give some false positives.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. "what if you call multiple times" for me looks like doing too much work in one method. Can you please show the action method you want to test?

Comment: So what I mean is the example given in the above question where I am setting up two different expectations on the UserRepository. In my test code I want to verify it is called twice in two precise ways and provide two different results. In your example I search for the result in a list but in the second call to it Get is still looking at the first list so it won't find the user set up in the list set up in the second expectation

Comment: In real world your controller will act on one and the same repository, right. This means that your test should do the same. I.e. prepare a list, which satisfies both queries. If the list can produce false positives, this means that your real application can provide them too, i.e. the code is not concrete enough.

Comment: You're absolutely right and my only objection is the way I set up the expectations which is line by line using SpecFlow so one expectation set up can be used by multiple tests, therefore one data set does not fit all purposes. I will have a play and see if I can make it work. I have working code for Rhino btw just not quite how I want it to work