# Mocking LINQ Expressions - Moq

Tags: c#, mocking, expression, moq, moq-3

How do I mock something that is - Expression> using Moq?

I'm trying to mock a call to my repo layer that takes in a LINQ Expression for constructing a query. I'm trying the below syntax but it fails. The SearchFor method doesn't get called.

```
var array = new Employee[1];

array[0] = new Employee() { ID = 1234, Name = "Test" };

MockEmployeeRepo.Setup(x => x.SearchFor(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>>()))
            .Returns(array.AsQueryable);

var list = EmployeeService.GetEmployees("Test");

MockEmployeeRepo.Verify(x => x.SearchFor(x1 => x1.Name == "Test"), Times.Once());

Assert.AreEqual("Test", list[0].Name);
```

Here the `GetEmployees` method looks like below.

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees(string name)
{
    return repo.SearchFor(x => x.Name == name);
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot verify expressions, What is SearchFor parameters taking? Is it an expression?

Comment: Correct. Its taking an expression. Any thoughts on how I would go about unit testing those?

Comment: Do you really need it to be an expression? Why you can't just pass in a string instead of an expression?

Comment: Because I believe, the SearchFor should just delegate it to the repository, and it will end up in the DbSet you can verify that given the name, it returned the correct results. At this level, I believe you can just verify that it called it.

Comment: I could do that but I'm trying to make the SearchFor method on my repository very generic so that it can act on any entity. Makes sense?

Comment: But are you injecting this mock repo into your EmployeeService? I don't see that in the above test...

Comment: Correct, I'm injecting a MockEmployeeRepo through the constructor. I didn't include that in the pasted code.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't verify with expressions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup and verify expression with Moq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570761/setup-and-verify-expression-with-moq)

Answer (score 1):

Moq does not supports with Expression function so here is the best solution. Use this nuget package [Moq.Expression](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoqExpression/)

```
// import namespace
using MoqExpression;

// it will work
MockEmployeeRepo.Setup(x => x.SearchFor(MoqHelper.IsExpression<Employee>(s => s.Name.Equals("Test")))).Returns(array.AsQueryable);
```

For more documentation: https://github.com/ovaishanif94/Moq.Expression

Comment: As of Oct 10, 2019 Moq.Expression only works for .Net Core. If anyone knows of a solution for .Net 4.7 (or any non .Net Core version) please reply.

Comment: @schwechel you can try like below.
.Setup(x => x.SearchFor(It.Is<Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>>(e => e.Body.ToString().Contains("x.Name")))).ReturnsAsync(array.AsQueryable)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you might be able to evaluate the expression into something comparable, like a `string`.

```cs
It.Is<Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>>(expression => SomeEvaluator.Evaluate (expression) == "Name = 'Test'");
```

In my case I wanted to mock queries to Azure Tables, so I used `Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient.CreateQueryFilter` for evaluation, i.e.:

```cs
It.Is<Expression<Func<TableEntity, bool>>> (query => TableClient.CreateQueryFilter (query) == "RowKey eq 'someId'")
```