# Mocked method still returns null

Tags: c#, .net, moq

In my new .Net Core project I decided to use Moq framework for a first time. After I set up all method according to tutorial I still getting Exception:

["The following setups were not matched:
IRepository`1 cr => cr.GetSingle(x => x.Key == 7028750f-044c-4862-999d-e21c4bfe7543) "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Ww3.png)

or after removing all VerifyAll() calls, a got null from serivice.
Any idea how to solve it?

Dependences:

- "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
- "Moq": "4.6.38-alpha",
- "xunit": "2.2.0-beta5-build3474",
- "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",

Character:

```
public class Character : IEntity
{
    ...
    public Guid Key { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Generic repository:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    TEntity GetSingle(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    ...
}
```

Unit of work:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{        
    IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IEntity;       
    ...
}
```

Characters service:

```
class CharactersService : ICharactersService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public CharactersService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public Character GetCharacterByKey(Guid characterKey)
    {
        var charactersRepository = _unitOfWork.Repository<Character>();
        var character = charactersRepository.GetSingle(ch => ch.Key == characterKey);
        return character;
    }
    ...
}
```

Test class:

```
public class CharactersServiceTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void GetCharacterByKey_CharacterExists_ReturnsCharacter()
    {
        //Arrange
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var characterFromDb = new Character { Key = guid };

        var characterRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository<Character>>();
        characterRepositoryMock.Setup(cr => cr.GetSingle(x => x.Key == guid)).Returns(characterFromDb);
        characterRepositoryMock.VerifyAll();

        var unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        unitOfWorkMock.Setup(uow => uow.Repository<Character>()).Returns(characterRepositoryMock.Object);
        unitOfWorkMock.VerifyAll();

        var charactersService = new CharactersService(unitOfWorkMock.Object);

        //Act
        var character = charactersService.GetCharacterByKey(guid);

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(character);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be calling VerifyAll *after* the test has completed in order to verify that your expectations were met during the test...

Comment: I agree with @Will, the `VerifyAll` method is used to verify that all expectations set have been met for that mocked class. So any methods you have setup you may wish to verify that it has been called correctly, therefore the `VerifyAll` function is a helper so that you don't have to call it for each verification that you wish to make.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup and verify expression with Moq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570761/setup-and-verify-expression-with-moq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that you compare two expressions:

First in `characterRepositoryMock.Setup` : `x => x.Key == guid` 
And the second one in `GetCharacterByKey` Method:  `ch => ch.Key == characterKey`

They are not identical because they point to two different Expression objects.
If you really want to test it such way, you should check, that both expressions get the same `GUID` value:

```
characterRepositoryMock.Setup(cr => 
  cr.GetSingle(It.Is<Expression<Func<Character, bool>>>(x =>check(x, guid)) ))
 .Returns(characterFromDb);
```

With this check method:

```
public bool check(Expression<Func<Character,bool>> x, Guid guid)
{
    var body = x.Body as BinaryExpression;  
    var g = (Guid) Expression.Lambda(body.Right).Compile().DynamicInvoke(); 
    return g == guid;
}
```

And, yes i agree with comments, `VerifyAll`  should be called **after** all, in Assert part.

Comment: `VerifyAll()` won't do you anything if you did not put `.Verifiable()` on your setup statements.